# How do I adjust the top margin of a Caroufredsel slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, caroufredsel

I've got a Caroufredsel slider working fine using the "custom" settings from the samples:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // Using custom configuration
            $("#random_selections").carouFredSel({
                items : 3,
                direction : "up",
                /*wrapper: {
                    margin:0px,
                },*/
                scroll : {
                    items : 1,
                    easing : "elastic",
                    duration : 1000,
                    pauseOnHover : true
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

However, the image at the top is not flush with the top border of the container. If I check the debugger, I see that there is CSS styling at the  level from within the .js library:

```
 <div class="caroufredsel_wrapper" style="display: block; text-align: start; float: none; position: relative; top: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: auto; z-index: auto; width: 400px; height: 1387px; margin: 16px 0px; overflow: hidden;">
```

I have discovered that this particular element is controlled by the margin attribute. How can I adjust this attribute to reflect "margin: 0px 0px" without altering the code in the library? Is there a way to do this externally?

There is little activity in the Caroufredsel support forums, and it's not clear from the configuration pages how to adjust this.

Comment: well is this js using a stylesheet? if so change it.

Comment: No, the styling is inline.

Answer (score 1):

You could locate the class that controls that element in the stylesheet(s), see if it's generated there. Maybe there's some child elements of your class that are overwriting your inline CSS

Comment: The inline CSS isn't being overwritten -- the problem is that the inline CSS is within the .js libraries and that takes precedence over my external CSS. I've just resolved it, though using relative positioning.

Comment: Okay, so I've resolved this issue by applying the following CSS to my div that was serving as the container for the Caroufredsel code:

position: absolute;
top: -16px;

Sort of a workaround, really, just reversing the inline positioning within the .js script.